# How to add an extra parameter to queryset results before render?

Tags: django, django-views

I have this queryset:

```
topics = Topic.objects.select_related('creator').filter(forum=forum_id).order_by("-created")
```

I'd like to add to each topic, before rendring to template, an additional boolean field `is_unread`, which is calculated in the view based on another model. This field is not in Topic model and should be calculated for each request.user separately in the views.

The pseudo-code of the business logic is like this:

```
for topic in topics: 
   if topic.lastposted > request.user.lastvisit.thistopic:
      topic.is_unread = True
```

The model that contains lastvist is this:

```
class LastVisitedTopic(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    forum = models.ForeignKey(Forum)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    lastvisited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

When I print out `topics` it gives a bunch of objects:

```
[<Topic: Topic object>, <Topic: Topic object>, <Topic: Topic object>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']
```

So I'm not sure how to append the `is_unread` to them. So appreciate your hints..

Comment: Doesn't your code work?

Comment: What is your Django version?

Comment: @ShangWang not sure where to apply the that `else`. Could  you elaborate your answer?

Comment: is_unread is a field in Topic model?

Comment: @Gocht no. It's a separate parameter calculated for each user on request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way should be working, but it's a little hard to manage. You should create a property method on your `Topic` class and call it instead:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    # some fields go there
    @property
    def is_unread(self):
        if self.last_posted > self.visitor.lasthit:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Then when you do `topic.is_unread` without the brackets it would return the value you want.

Python [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).

**Edit**:

Sounds like OP doesn't have all parameters reside on `Topic` model. In this case it falls back to the original implementation:

```
for topic in topics: 
    if topic.lastposted > request.user.lastvisit.thistopic:
        topic.is_unread = True
    else:
        topic.is_unread = False
```

In your template you could do:

```
{% for topic in topics %}
    {{ topic.is_unread }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Well the problem is that I have no `visitor` field in Topic fields. `visitor` that I've mentioned is in fact just `request.user` who GETs the page.

Comment: Your code does not reflect that. You have `topic.visitor`, which means it's a field on `topic`. I will edit my answer to cover that, but you should also edit your code to make it less confusing.

Comment: It makes perfect sense but I still have issue converting the pseudo-code to actual code.  Will you please update your answer, regarding the model that I've added?

Comment: I'm lack of information about your logic. My best guess is that `if a person's last visit over all is earlier than current topic's last visit, then it's unread`?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. The logic is: If a topic has posts which are more recent than a user's last visit to the topic, then the topic is unread for that user.